# Запись сообщения в переменную VK_API

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Мне нужно записать ответ пользователя в переменную , но есть одна проблема , python записывает в переменную не URL , а саму команду "заказать рекламу" ,
может я делаю что - то не так ?

```
            elif "заказать рекламу" in event.text.lower() :
                 vk.messages.send(user_id=event.user_id,message="Пришлите URL как это указано в инструкции :",random_id=random.randint(1,10000000000000000000))
                 if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me and event.text:
                     advert = event.text
```

Вот запись из консоли :

Получено сообщение: а от 462646628 в 2020-01-21 21:19:13.034000

Получено сообщение: Заказать рекламу  от 462646628 в 2020-01-21 21:19:14.517000

Полученный URL : Заказать рекламу

Получено сообщение: https://i.ibb.co/169RSL1 от 462646628 в 2020-01-21 21:19:36.687000

Comment: Мне кажется, вы показали слишком маленький кусок кода. В любом случае код с обработкой ответа мне кажется должен быть не внутри кода посылки сообщения.

Answer (score 0):

Причиной того, что в переменную записывается "Заказать рекламу", а не ответ пользователя является то, что вы записываете в эту переменную сообщение из **текущего** события, а не из следующего. Текущим событием является получение сообщения "Заказать рекламу".

Вариант решения вашей задачи - после того, как вы требуете от человека URL, указать, что следующее его сообщение нужно записать в `advert`

Пример реализации:

```py
waiting_url_users = set() # эта строка должна находиться вне цикла слушателя событий (перед ним)
...
    # это условие становится первым в списке событий
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW \
    and event.user_id in waiting_url_users \
    and event.text:
        advert = event.text
        waiting_url_users.remove(event.user_id)
        # тут дальнейшая обработка advert

        ...
    elif "заказать рекламу" in event.text.lower() :
        vk.messages.send(user_id=event.user_id,message="Пришлите URL как это указано в инструкции :",random_id=random.randint(1,10000000000000000000))

        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW \
        and event.to_me \
        and event.text:
            waiting_url_users.add(event.user_id)
        ...
```